# Garbage Collection Test Fails?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using a Dictionary with weak keys to test if an object has been garbage collected. When all references to the object outside of the dictionary are removed, I expect the dictionary to no longer be populated. It seems to work for an Object, but for a Sprite it indicates that the garbage collection hasn't taken place. Can anyone tell me what I am overlooking?

```
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

var dictionary:Dictionary=new Dictionary(true);
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,collectionTest);
var sprite:Sprite=new Sprite();
dictionary[sprite]=true;
sprite=null;
trace(sprite);//traces null

function collectionTest(event:Event):void{
    var cleared:Boolean = true;
    for each (var key:* in dictionary) {
        cleared = false;
    }
    if (cleared) {
        trace("Collection Success.");
    } else {
        trace("Collection Failure");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would delete the key as a best practice:

```
dictionary[sprite] = null;
delete dictionary[sprite];
```

Note that weak keys indicates the key is eligible for garbage collection and is removed from the table when the object is collected.  It would be unlikely for Garbage Collection to occur immediately within your function.

Dictionary will never remove weak String keys from the table.

There are some known issues regarding methods as keys and AMF serialization.

You need to engage some memory allocation to trigger Garbage Collection.

Using your example, I created 1,500 Sprites and the key was removed within 4-frames:

Output:

> null 
>   Collection Failure 
>   Collection Failure 
>   Collection Failure 
>   Collection Success.

Example code:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {

        public var dictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);

        public function Test()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collectionTest);
            var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            dictionary[sprite] = true;
            sprite = null;
            trace(sprite); //traces null
        }

        protected function collectionTest(event:Event):void
        {
            var cleared:Boolean = true;
            for each (var key:* in dictionary)
            {
                cleared = false;
            }
            if (cleared)
                trace("Collection Success.");
            else
                trace("Collection Failure");

            for(var i:uint = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                new Sprite();
            }
        }
    }
}
```